# how to use -interaction=batchmode but at same time stop and display to terminal when an error shows up?

Tags: luatex, compiling, batchmode

I did an experiment and found using `-interaction=batchmode` with lualatex reduces the compile time the most on one large latex file I have. Down from 77 minutes to 45 minutes.  All on Linux WSL-2 Ubuntu 20.04. This was even faster than using `lualatex foo.tex >/dev/null`  (55 minutes) since the output was eliminated right from the source, and no output was even needed to be redirected to `/dev/null`

http://latexref.xyz/Command-line-options.html

Therefore I want to change my Makefiles to use this. The big problem is, I no longer see the errors now on the screen when they happen. Everything goes to the log file.

Is there a way to use `-interaction=batchmode` but make it stop *and* display the error on the screen?  Otherwise, I have to now open the log file each time to find if the file compiled with or without error.

This is not practical as I have 10's of thousands of Latex files to compile and I need to stop and see the error message when it happens, and not later.

Here is a MWE with an error

```
\documentclass{report}%   
\begin{document}

This is a test

\sin x
\end{document}
```

Now

```
>lualatex -interaction=batchmode foo.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)
 restricted system commands enabled.
>
```

Nothing displays on the screen. The error does show up in the log file. I also tried

```
>lualatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode foo.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)
 restricted system commands enabled.
>
```

Is there a way to make batchmode display the compile errors on the screen and stop then?

I use Lualatex only.

**Update**

Thanks to hint checking the exist status of Lualatex is all what is needed to find if it completed successfully or not. No need to look in the logfile.

[image]

Comment: Wow, those must be *huge* documents. Have you tried playing with various options from the [`silence`](https://ctan.org/pkg/silence?lang=en) package to reduce the output you don't need and focus on only on what you want in errorstopmode? I don't know how that affects compilation time, but if batchmode helps, it might help.

Comment: You don't need to open the log to determine if the compilation changed since you can just look at the exit status: TeX only exits with 0 indicating success if there weren't any errors.

Comment: @frabjous actually this document is medium size. I have some that take 4 hrs to compile. I tried silence but it had no effect really and hard to use and configure for everything I need eliminated. Fastest is batchmode as it eliminate output from the source.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but I have to ask, what is medium size to you? (In terms of number of pages, and filesize of PDF?) My biggest document is an 800 page book that takes 16 seconds to compile on an 8-year old computer. By that math, yours would be over 100,000 pages long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to determine if an error happened or not, you can look at the exit status of the `lualatex` command: It will be 0 if no error happened, otherwise it will be 1. In case of an error you can then look into the log file.

If you want to see errors directly you can also use Lua callbacks.

Create a file `mybatchmode.lua` containing

```lua
texconfig.interaction = 0           -- Activate batchmode
texconfig.halt_on_error = true -- Stop at first error

callback.register('show_error_message', function(...)
  texio.write_nl('term and log', status.lasterrorstring)
  texio.write('term', '.\n')
end)
callback.register('show_lua_error_hook', function(...)
  texio.write_nl('term and log', status.lastluaerrorstring)
  texio.write('term', '.\n')
end)
```

and then run

```
lualatex -lua=mybatchmode.lua file
```

For the example file in your question this would result in

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)
 restricted system commands enabled.
! Missing $ inserted.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
lualatex --interaction=batchmode file || cat file.log
```

so it only shows the log on error